# How to perform Dickey Fuller with adf.test() with .txt data?

Tags: r, statistics

How can I perform a Dickey Fuller in R with adf.test() with this PS1.txt data?
I got this error:

> adf.test(data2)
> Fehler in adf.test(data2) : x is not a vector or univariate time series

Please help with coding.

```
install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE)
library(tseries)

data<- read.table(file.choose(),header=FALSE, sep = ";")
head(data)

data2 <- na.omit(data)
head(data2)

adf.test(data2)
```

Comment: you're going to have to give us the data or a better reprex if you want help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

For tab separated data, use "\t" as separator:

```
install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE)
library(tseries)

data<- read.table(file.choose(),header=FALSE, sep = "\t")
View(data)

data2 <- na.omit(data)

data3 <- as.vector(t(data2))

adf.test(data3)
```

Be aware that the `adf.test` will take long for a very large number of datapoints. Aggregating of taking a subset can be used to decrease the number of observations.

Comment: @AMoz These are the columnnames. Here, instead of head(data) use View(data) to see the values.